# pyautocad - automate drawing - import DWG - write text - import image

Tags: python, autocad, autocad-scripts

i'm not a professional coder and i'm so sorry for my english :)
i hope you understand.

I'm trying to automate part of my job.
i have to create dwg; every layer for me is a sheet (like A4 paper), for that reason i have to change layer and import specific dwg/dxf from my repository symbol.

For example i have to:
(start new project)
open newproject.dwg
(paste dwg)
import C:\repository_cad\symbol1.dwg in layer n°3 with coordinate X 100 Y 200.
(write text in the middle of symbol)
write "SYMBOL_1" layer n°3 coordinate X 150 Y200 alignment center.
(insert logo image)
import C:\repository_cad\image1.jpg in coordinate X 10 Y 20

i'm trying to use pyautocad, but i cant find a command for import dxf, and i dont find information about changing layer.
i find out only the command for draw the line, circle ecc, but if i have to re-draw all my repository by python i need to much time, i hope is possible copy draw from another dwg and paste it in my new dwg.

can someone give to me a little help with these 3 command?
maybe is not possible making this stuff on pyautocad? is there other library for python?

i read the docs but i dont see info about some import function.
so, i tried:

```
from pyautocad import Autocad, APoint
acad = Autocad(create_if_not_exists=False)
acad.prompt("Hello, Autocad from Python\n")
print (acad.doc.Name)
```

and it's works, on autocad terminal i can see "Hello, Autocad from Python"
in the Docs i find out how write a autocad-command from python.
The function is:
prompt()
i tried:

```
acad.prompt('-INSERT') #-INSERT is the autocad command for import dxf or dwg
acad.prompt('C:\SPAC\Librerie\Elettr\02-15-04.dwg')#this is the path of the cad
acad.prompt('-15 -15') #coord X Y of the point where i want to paste
acad.prompt('1') # 1 is the scale factor in X
acad.prompt('1') # 1 is the scale factor in Y (autocad askt first in X and after in Y
acad.prompt('0') #degree of rotation
```

at this point i havent error on python and no error on autocad terminal, but the draw not appear on cad

thanks
Max

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service. You are expected to try to write the code yourself. After doing [more research](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) if you have a problem you can post what you've tried with a clear explanation of what isn't working and providing a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). I suggest reading [How to Ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). Also, be sure to [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: I haven't use pyautocad, but the [docs are here](https://pyautocad.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) and [this page](https://pyautocad.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html) seems like a good place to start.

Answer (score 2):

acad.prompt() will just echo the string to the command line. What you are looking for is acad.doc.SendCommand(), e.g.

```
acad.doc.SendCommand('-INSERT ')
```

Notice there is a blank space after the autocad command, that stands for  to activate the command.

Answer (score 0):

go through the Object Model (ActiveX) of autocad website which will help you to code/use more objects/tools of the pyautocad

https://help.autodesk.com/view/OARX/2022/ENU/?guid=GUID-A809CD71-4655-44E2-B674-1FE200B9FE30
for further information you may take the course "Learn Automation of AutoCAD using python" from udemy